# A call to Bind must be assigned to a property of a control inside a template

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I want to show a thumbnail image inside a gridview instead of the text.  This is what I am trying:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="Image">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="thumbnail" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Bind("Image") %>" />                        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

What is the syntax i should be using?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- Try using **Eval** instead of *Bind* for the ImageUrl - this is one way binding.
- If you are still having problems, using single quotes instead of double quotes around the property might help: `<asp:Image ID="thumbnail" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />`

Comment: had to use single quotes as u mentioned.  worked wonderfully thanks